# Comparar array php multidimensional

Tags: php, array, comparaciones

Tengo la siguiente problemática, lo que sucede es que tengo un array php de la siguiente forma (extracto del array original):

```
Array(
  [id_4062] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2191
        [1] => 65
        [2] => 8904
    )

[id_4056] => Array
    (
        [0] => 60
        [1] => 3508
    )
)
```

El cual necesito comparar con este otro array (es un pequeño fragmento del original):

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_distributors] => 2191
        [name_distributors] => Empresa 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_distributors] => 65
        [name_distributors] => Empresa 2
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id_distributors] => 60
        [name_distributors] => Empresa 45
    )
)
```

Necesito comparar y reemplazar en el primer array para obtener algo como esto:

```
Array(
 [id_4062] => Array(
    [id_distribuidores] => 2191,65
    [name_distribuidores] => Empresa 1, Empresa 2
)
 [id_4056] => Array(
    [id_distribuidores] => 60
    [name_distribuidores] => Empresa 45
 )
)
```

En verdad que he tratado por varios métodos, con array replace, array por referencia, etc y nada mas no obtengo lo que necesito, si alguien me pudiese ayudar si los agradecería infinitamente

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 1):

Este código debería servirte, aunque hay otras formas de hacerlo como array_walk o similares.

```
    $groupedIds= [
      'id_4062' => [2191, 65, 8904],
      'id_4056' => [60, 3508]
    ];

    $distributors = [
      [
        'id_distributors' => 2191,
        'name_distributors' => 'Empresa 1'
      ],
      [
        'id_distributors' => 65,
        'name_distributors' => 'Empresa 2'
      ],
      [
        'id_distributors' => 60,
        'name_distributors' => 'Empresa 45'
      ]
    ];

    $return = [];

    // Recorremos los distributors para obtener cada id_distributors que se va a buscar
    foreach ($distributors as $distributor) {

      // Recorremos los groupedIds para obtener los grupos de ids en los que se va a buscar mediante la función array_search el id_distributors obtenido
      foreach ($groupedIds as $groupedId => $ids) {

        // Buscamos en cada grupo de ids el id_distributors obtenido.
        // La función array_search busca un elemento en un array y devuelve la posición en la que se ha encontrado, o false si no lo ha encontrado.
        // Cuando hay alguna coincidencia se añaden los valores del distributor a un nuevo array de salida.
        if (array_search($distributor['id_distributors'], $ids) === false) {

          $prev_id_distributors = (!empty($return[$groupedId]['id_distributors']) ? $return[$groupedId]['id_distributors'] . ',' : '');

          $prev_name_distributors = (!empty($return[$groupedId]['name_distributors']) ? $return[$groupedId]['name_distributors'] . ',' : '');

          $return[$groupedId] = [
            'id_distributors' => $prev_id_distributors . $distributor['id_distributors'],
            'name_distributors' => $prev_name_distributors . $distributor['name_distributors']
          ];
        }
      } 
    }

    print_r($return);
```

Comment: Por favor considera agregar una explicación, de modo que sepamos como esto soluciona el problema expuesto